# How to integrate aar library to native module in React Native?

Tags: android, react-native, aar, native-module

I need to integrate aar library to my native module. So, I created structure of the package by `create-react-native-module`, then I created new folder `libs` and added `implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.aar"])` to `build.gradle` in my package

[screenshot](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/49447404/151804199-de73272d-fe25-434d-bd66-c5a537b78ae3.png)

Then I import my class from my aar into my module. And it works fine. Build without errors:

[screenshot](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/49447404/151804385-310a0cc0-7b7e-4346-8631-0781cb352e90.png)

But when I import this class in `MainApplication.java` of the test app I get an error:

[screenshot](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/49447404/151805041-778003a1-a8a4-4251-bc0d-d1b9c95fb94d.png)

[screenshot](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/49447404/151805482-13f00fa5-4e42-4feb-8a83-b20e38a6cde3.png)

What I missed?
Help me please! Thanks.